# Balanced Audio Line Driver Off Single Supply

Tags: audio, dc, differential, single-supply-op-amp, balancing

I am working on a device that needs a balanced audio line driver that can convert an unbalanced signal to balanced and drive a balanced cable run between devices. I am looking at schematics using devices like the THAT1646 and also op-amp circuits that can do this, but the all seem to run off a bipolar supply (+/-15V, +/-12V, +/-9V, +/-5V, etc), whereas my device needs to run off a single ended supply (+9V only).

Does anyone have a circuit they can share to do this on a single ended supply?

Update: Would prefer to avoid using audio transformers. Looking for an IC or op-amp based solution.

Update: Looking for output to be hot, cold, ground (3 wire). This is meant for balanced xlr audio connections.

Comment: The SSM2142 does this although it's becoming obsolete, but I expect you can still find some. Or is it for a new product?

Comment: Do you care whether you have a two wire balanced line, or a three wire? (2 signal and 1 ground?) Are OK with using transformers?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy just added updates. 3 wire, no transformers.

Comment: How many of these devices are you making? How much design/test/debug effort should go into project compared to simpler but more expensive per device solutions?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy probably a fairly small run at first (5-10 units), but each device needs 8 independent balanced outputs, so some reduction of cost is prefereable

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy that said, using a more expensive single IC solution like the THAT1646 or DRV134 is totally fine. This just all needs to fit inside a 1590XX aluminum enclosure so having 8 audio transformers isn't really going to work out.

Comment: If you need 8 independent balanced outputs, then why not add a DC to DC converter to get the negative rail for a bipolar supply. You only need to do that once per device, and then you can use a simple bipolar balanced driver, rather than repeating circuitry 8 times.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy In my experience positive to negative switching converters tend to be extremely noisy. It's been a while since I've tried it, but I haven't had success using one in an audio application.

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with using transformers, a simple audio transformer with a center tapped secondary will convert from unbalanced / single-ended input to 3-wire balanced output, and does not require a bipolar power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0BK6g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit, the transformer needs to be able to tolerate whatever DC component may be present in your unbalanced input.

Also, it is assumed in this circuit that whatever is driving the single-ended unbalanced input and the transformer primary have suitably matched impedances. Similarly for the secondary impedance. That is, not just any transformer will do.

You can eliminate the DC component entering the transformer by adding a capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffHaOV.png)</sup>

However, you still need to ensure that the transformer's impedance is suitable for the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified that you do not want to use transformers, here is a circuit that may possibly suit your needs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuuvQw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op-amps can be single supply. They are biased to 1/2 of Vcc.

This circuit will run in the CircuitLab simulator.

Since you may be using 8 of these circuits per device, there is a small optimization you can make. You could use 10k\$\Omega\$ resistors for R3 and R4 and share the divided voltage across all the circuits. Not a huge savings, but some.